# Function returning None - from list

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I have the following function:

```
def createListofParts(testbenchParts, testbench, ttype):
    partList = []
    for part in ttype:
        for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(os.path.join(testbenchParts, part)):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.svn-base'):
                    pass
                elif file.endswith('all-wcprops'):
                    pass
                elif file.endswith('entries'):
                    pass
                else:
                    partList.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    createMatchTuples(partList, testbench)

def createMatchTuples(partList, testbench):
    XMLlist = glob.glob(os.path.join(testbench, 'Scripts', "*.xml"))
    matchList = []
    for part in partList:
        matches = 0
        for xmlFile in XMLlist:
            xml = open(xmlFile, 'r')
            t = re.findall('/' + os.path.split(part)[1], xml.read().replace('\\','/'))
            matches = matches + len(t)
            xml.close()
        matchList.append((os.path.split(part)[1], matches))
    print matchList
    print type(matchList)
    return matchList
```

Which prints a list of tuples and then type = List

This function is called

```
matchList = functions.createListofParts(testbenchParts, testbench, ttype)
print matchList
print type(matchList)
```

but now prints None, ie the matchList is converted from List in 1st function to None!

I just don't understand whats going on here

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In createMatchTuples(partList, testbench), shouldn't you `return createMatchTuples(partList, testbench)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createListofParts` has no return so as all functions that don't have a return value, it returns None by default so `matchList = functions.createListofParts(testbenchParts, testbench, ttype)` sets `matchList` to `None`, You need to `return createMatchTuples`:

```
def createListofParts(testbenchParts, testbench, ttype):
    partList = []
    for part in ttype:
        for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(os.path.join(testbenchParts, part)):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.svn-base'):
                    pass
                elif file.endswith('all-wcprops'):
                    pass
                elif file.endswith('entries'):
                    pass
                else:
                    partList.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return createMatchTuples(partList, testbench) # <- return
```

Comment: Right! so even though the createListofParts is calling the createMatchTuples which returns something it will ALWAYS be none?! So would it better to combine the two functions or call them twice? ie first one returning partslist and 2nds retuning the matchList? Thanks

Comment: Just add a return statement to `createListofParts`.

Comment: Done that! Thanks guys much appreciated! I love how quickly the StackOverflow community responds.

Comment: @T1M : createMatchTuples returns the matchList object to createListofParts, but createListofParts doesn't save it or return it, so the matchList object gets cleaned up by the Python garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's because `createListofParts` does not have a return statement and in python, by default, if there's no return statement, a function returns `None`.